# Share 1 instance of dependencies between multiple Android modules

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to break my app into multiple libraries and utilize Dagger2 to inject dependencies. To start, I broke the app into 2 Android modules. Login takes place in the App module and everything else is in the Core library.

The App structure currently looks like this:

```
Android Application
├── App Module (Only has login)
|   └── Core Library
├── Core Library
|   └── Networking library
    └── Cert Pinning Library
└── Networking Library
└── Cert Pinning Library
```

I want to share the same instance of the networking library and cert pinning library between the App module and the Core library.

My Dagger files look like this:

```
   //AppComponent
   @Component(modules = { AppModule.class, CoreModule.class CertificatePinnerModule.class, NetworkingModule.class}) @Singleton public interface AppComponent {
     void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
     }

    //AppModule
     @Module public class AppModule {}

    //CoreComponent
    @Component(modules = {
        CoreModule.class CertificatePinnerModule.class, NetworkingModule.class
    })        
    @Singleton public interface CoreComponent {
    //a bunch of injection locations
    }


    //CoreModule
    @Module public class CoreModule {}

    //CertPinnerModule
    @Module public class CertificatePinnerModule {}

    //NetworkingModule
    @Module public class NetworkingModule {}

    //NetworkingSupportComponent
    @Component(modules = {NetworkingModule.class,     
    CertificatePinnerModule.class}) @Singleton
    public interface NetworkingSupportComponent {

    }

    //Application class
    public class Application extends Application {  
      private AppComponent component;  

      @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
     CoreModule coreModule = new CoreModule(this);
        CoreInjector.init(coreModule); //DaggerCoreComponent builder
    component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().coreModule(coreModule).appModule(getAppModule()).build();
    NetworkingSupport.init(this); //DaggerNetworkingSupportComponent builder
 }
 }
```

Currently this code compiles but the App module and Core library use different instances of the NetworkingModule and the CertificatePinnerModule. I tried modifying the AppComponent to look like this:

```
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class }, dependencies = { CoreComponent.class }) @Singleton public interface AppComponent {
```

but that doesn't compile since the App Module can't see the providers defined in the CoreModule.

If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I think you should have a component per scope, not per... "library" or whatever. Libraries should expose modules. Although I wonder how you'd ensure that they are scoped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I understand what you're getting at. I'll try messing around with scoped components and see if I can get it working. BTW +1 for your awesome library Simple-Stack.

Comment: There are a few posts around about multi-module gradle projects using dagger. If you search a bit you might be able to find one. I think you have to pass the component from the root module into other modules or the bound instances you want to share